# NullPointer when minifyEnabled is set to true

Tags: java, android

I have an issue with my app when `minifyEnabled` is set to `true` in my `build.gradle`

The items in the `RecyclerView` are shown without any property (so no description, no other stuff, it's like an empty object is added to `RecyclerView`) in it and when it try to make any action on some of items in that `RecyclerView` i get a `NullPointer` (while if `minifyEnabled` is set to false all works as it have to)

One of points where the app crashes is the following at the line with equals:

```
public Menu.Prodotti getItem(Menu.Prodotti prodotto) {
    for (Menu.Prodotti item : items) {
        if (item.codice.equals(prodotto.codice) && item.jump == prodotto.jump) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
> referenc

It seems like `Menu.Prodotti` is minified and it's can't be load.

But in my `proguard-rules` i've added the whole `Menu` class to be ignored from minifizing, what else should i try to do?

Here is my `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.models.Menu
-keepclassmembers class it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.models.Menu { *; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was easier than i tought i had to include the inner classes by adding `$*` to `-keep class`

So my `proguard-rules.pro` looks like this now and all is working as it have to:

```
-keep class it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.models.Menu$* { *; }
-keepclassmembers class it.gabtamagnini.visualposmobile.models.Menu { *; }
```